# Google OR-Tools: Minimize Total Time

Tags: or-tools

I am working on a VRPTW and want to minimize the total time (travel time + waiting time) cumulated for all vehicles. So if we have 2 vehicles one that starts at time 0 and returns at time 50 and one that starts at time 25 and returns at time 100, then the objective value would be 50+75=125.
Currently I have implemented the following code:

```
    for i in range(data['num_vehicles']):
        routing.AddVariableMinimizedByFinalizer(
            time_dimension.CumulVar(routing.End(i)))
```

However, this seems like it is only minimizing the time we arrive back at the depot. 
Also it results in very high waiting times.
How do I implement it correctly in Google OR tools?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is called the span.

See the [SetSpanCostCoefficientForVehicle method](http://google.github.io/or-tools/python/ortools/constraint_solver/pywrapcp.html#pywrapcp.RoutingDimension.SetSpanCostCoefficientForVehiclehttps://) for one vehicle.

You can also [set it for all vehicles](http://google.github.io/or-tools/python/ortools/constraint_solver/pywrapcp.html#pywrapcp.RoutingDimension.SetSpanCostCoefficientForAllVehicles).